React handle Change / Set State only works once before I have to reset
I have this program that should show all of my images and when I click a check box, filter them down to the specified attribute. However, it only seems to work once when I reload the page and then any time I click a checkbox the filter doesn't update. I am new to react, am i using setState or handleChange wrong?
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FilterBar from './FilterBar';

const images = [
  { id: 1, colour: 'colour', location: 'Rocky Mountains', theme: 'landscape', url: "images/websiteimage1.jpg" },
  { id: 2, colour: 'colour', location: 'Rocky Mountains', theme: 'landscape', url: "images/websiteimage2.jpg" },
  { id: 3, colour: 'colour', location: 'Rocky Mountains', theme: 'animals', url: "images/websiteimage15.jpg" },
  { id: 4, colour: 'colour', location: 'Rocky Mountains', theme: 'animals', url: "images/websiteimage18.jpg" },
  { id: 5, colour: 'colour', location: 'Johnstown', theme: 'architecture', url: "images/websiteimage55.jpg" },
  { id: 6, colour: 'colour', location: 'Drumheller', theme: 'architecture', url: "images/websiteimage51.jpg" },
];

const Gallery = () => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    colour: [],
    location: [],
    theme: []
  });

  const handleChange = (category, value) => {
    setFilters((filters) => {
      const newFilters = { ...filters };
      if (newFilters[category].includes(value)) {
        newFilters[category] = newFilters[category].filter(item => item !== value);
      } else {
        newFilters[category].push(value);
      }
      return newFilters;
    });
  };

  const filteredImages = images.filter(image => {
    return (
      (filters.colour.length === 0 || filters.colour.includes(image.colour)) &&
      (filters.location.length === 0 || filters.location.includes(image.location)) &&
      (filters.theme.length === 0 || filters.theme.includes(image.theme))
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="filter-bar">
      <div className="filter-category">
        <h3>Colour</h3>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.colour.includes('b/w')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('colour', 'b/w')}
          />
          B/W
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.colour.includes('colour')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('colour', 'colour')}
          />
          Colour
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="filter-category">
        <h3>Location</h3>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.location.includes('Johnstown')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('location', 'Johnstown')}
          />
          Johnstown
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.location.includes('St Lawrence River')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('location', 'St Lawrence River')}
          />
          St Lawrence River
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.location.includes('Rocky Mountains')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('location', 'Rocky Mountains')}
          />
          Rocky Mountains
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.location.includes('Drumheller')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('location', 'Drumheller')}
          />
          Drumheller
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.location.includes('Charleston Lake')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('location', 'Charleston Lake')}
          />
          Charleston Lake
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="filter-category">
        <h3>Theme</h3>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.theme.includes('landscape')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('theme', 'landscape')}
          />
          Landscape
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.theme.includes('animals')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('theme', 'animals')}
          />
          Animals
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.theme.includes('people')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('theme', 'people')}
          />
          People
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.theme.includes('architecture')}
            onChange={() => handleChange('theme', 'architecture')}
          />
          Architecture
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div className="image-gallery">
        {filteredImages.map(image => (
          <img key={image.id} src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + image.url} alt={image.category} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;


I had originally put filter Bar in its own component and moved it directly into gallery because I wasn't sure that you could change props inside the child element. I am not sure what to try, reading line by line it seems to at least make sense to me, but I am not sure
